# WSA Connection refused even though the host is not present

Tags: c, sockets, winapi

I'm writing a code to discover the devices on the network and this is just a part of it.

I'm trying to discover a host by establishing an socket connection with the host on port 80.

It connects well on some of the hosts on port 80 as the devices are listening on port 80. At times the **connect** function returns error as `WSACONNECTIONREFUSED` as there is no web service running on the host.

It is surprising to see that when i try to establish an socket connection on invalid ip addresses I get `WSACONNECTIONREFUSED` instead of `WSAETIMEDOUT`.

I googled and found out that the antivirus and firewall can cause the problems and i have disabled both on the scanning machine but no luck what could be causing the problem?

I have posted the code below:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
  WSADATA wsaData;
  int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
  if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
  {
    wprintf(L"WSAStartup function failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
  }
  SOCKET ConnectSocket;
  ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

  if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
  {
    wprintf(L"socket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
  }
  sockaddr_in clientService;
  clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;

  clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.4.28"); //No Host by this ip   address 

  clientService.sin_port = htons(80); //Port is 80 

  iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR *) &clientService,
      sizeof(clientService));

  printf("The socket connect return status : %d ", iResult);
  if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
  {

    wprintf(L"connect function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());

    iResult = closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
      wprintf(L"closesocket function failed with error: %ld\n",
          WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
  }

  wprintf(L"Connected to server.\n");

  iResult = closesocket(ConnectSocket);
  if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
  {
    printf("\n socket Connection failed ");
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
  }

  WSACleanup();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: try a ping on that IP address, you should get a host/network is unreachable. Btw. if there is really no host it should return WSAEHOSTUNREACH.

Comment: I have pinged the ip but its saying request timed out .The host itself is not there .

Comment: well, on my linux machine i get destination host unreachable. on windows I get a timeout, too. that seems to be some windows specific thing, sorry. But your program works as intended, if I run it on my windows machine. I get error 10060 WSAETIMEDOUT.

Comment: I'm getting a timeout on the same ip for another port by name 22 but not on port 80 . what could be the problem

Comment: The issue is resolved after adding an exception on the firewall for the program.Its working fine now.